# correcting $PATH so I can use NPM packages commands on MACOS with ZSH

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

echo $PATH says :

```
echo $PATH
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

When I run npm command, I get info and I can install packages.
I run

```
npm install npm-check-updates
```

When I go for npm list

```
npm list
username@ /Users/username
├── g@2.0.1
├── gatsby-plugin-sitemap@2.12.0
└── npm@8.17.0
```

But when I go for

```
which ncu
ncu not found

ncu -u
zsh: command not found: ncu
```

I tried to edit .zhrc acordingly to accepted answer in [59480260](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59480260/why-doesnt-zsh-recognize-command-from-globally-installed-npm-package), but it does not help at all. I guess the homebrew is my blocker?

Thank you for help! Im kind of lost in this PATH configurations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install this way:

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

That creates the file `/opt/homebrew/bin/ncu` for you.

Your path looks fine, as it contains `/opt/homebrew/`.

`ncu` should be in `/opt/homebrew/bin`:

```
% file /opt/homebrew/bin/ncu
/opt/homebrew/bin/ncu: a /usr/bin/env node script text executable, ASCII text
```

Of note, it is `.zshrc` not `.zhrc`.

Comment: This does not solve the problem unfortunately, the behaviour stays as it is with which ncu and ncu -u in the original question

Comment: Thank you for help, but the problem remains, 
`ls -l % -l /opt/homebrew/bin/`
`ls: %: No such file or directory`
`ls: -l: No such file or directory`

Im not sure what is wrong here. Maybe I have the NPM installed wrong way?

Comment: I have tried to run brew update and install, and sudenly the NCU works, maybe there was some issue? You gave me the idea to try this, thank you very much !